# com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: user.feature:11 - no step-definition method match found for: Match response

Tags: karate

Below is my feature file

```
Feature: Fetching user details
* url 'demourl'

Scenario: User Service

Given path 'demourl/User'
When method get
Then status 200
And Match response == { userId: '#number', username: 'XXX' }

* def userId = response.userId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
And match response == { userId: '#number', username: 'XXX' }
```

Note that `match` has to be all lower-case.